# Error de cors al subir videos a servidor en Google Run

Tags: nodejs, cors, angular8, google-cloud-functions

Tengo una aplicación en Angular 8.2 y Node js, normalmente subo imágenes, pero ahora intento subir videos.
Cuando desarrollo, conecto el front con la api local en el puerto 3000, los videos se suben correctamente, pero cuando conecto el front con la api que esta alojada en Google Run, arroja errores de cors en la consola del navegador. Todas las peticiones funcionan de forma correcta, incluso la misma ruta por la que subo videos también sube imágenes, pero con los videos ocurre el problema de los cors.

No he logrado definir la causa el problema, puesto que el servidor local es el mismo que el que coloque en Google Run.

Se los agradecería mucho si podrían opinar sobre la posible solución, muchas gracias

Este es el error de consola :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api-xxxxx-xxxx-uk.a.run.app/Inicio/ComentarioPbl' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

```js
HttpErrorResponse {
  error: ProgressEvent {
    bubbles: false,
    cancelBubble: false,
    cancelable: false,
    composed: false,
    currentTarget: XMLHttpRequest {...},
    defaultPrevented: false,
    eventPhase: 0,
    isTrusted: true,
    lengthComputable: false,
    loaded: 0,
    returnValue: true,
    srcElement: XMLHttpRequest {...},
    target: XMLHttpRequest {...},
    timeStamp: 1560513.8000000715,
    total: 0,
    type: 'error',
    ...
  },
  headers: HttpHeaders {
    headers: Map(0),
    lazyUpdate: null,
    normalizedNames: Map(0),
    ...
  },
  message: "Http failure response for https://api-xxxxxx-xxxxxxx-uk.a.run.app/Inicio/ComentarioPbl: 0 Unknown Error",
  name: "HttpErrorResponse",
  ok: false,
  status: 0,
  statusText: "Unknown Error",
  url: "https://api-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-uk.a.run.app/Inicio/ComentarioPbl",
  [[Prototype]]: HttpResponseBase
}
```

Adjunto tambien la api y Router  de la nube :

```js
/** app.js */

var express=require('express');
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var {database} =require('./keys');
var config=require('./config');
var app =config(express()); 
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var morgan=require('morgan');
var cors=require('cors');
var multer = require('multer');
var { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
var path = require('path');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

const imageFolderPath = 'public/img/uploads';
const vidFolderPath = 'public/vid/uploads';

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb ) => {
        if (file.mimetype.includes('image')) {
            cb(null, imageFolderPath);
        } else if (file.mimetype.includes('video')) {
            cb(null, vidFolderPath);
        } else {
            cb(new Error('Unsupported file type'), null);
        }
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb, filename) => {
        cb(null, uuidv4() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
}) 
app.use(multer({storage}).any());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Iniciando el servidor
server.listen(app.get('port'),()=>{
    console.log('Server on port',app.get('port'));
});

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.json()); 
app.use(cors());

mongoose.connect(database.uri, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
.then(db=>{
    console.log('DB is connected');
})
.catch(err=>console.error(err));

app.use('/Inicio/ComentarioPbl',require('./route/ComentarioPbl.route')); 



/**  route.js  */
const express=require('express');
const router=express.Router();
const ComentarioPbl = require('../controller/ComentarioPbl.Controller');
const isAuth =require('../services/auth.controller');

router.post('/',isAuth,ComentarioPbl.createComentario); // Metodo por el cual se puede publicar imagen o video

module.exports=router;
```

Comment: Estas poniendo tus cabeceras dos veces. Usa cors o headers. Solo usa `cors()` sin ninguna opción. Por defecto debería permitirte conectarte de donde sea. Esto para descartar algúna otra configuración extra.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder.  Acabo de actualizar el app.js y el route.js segun tus recomendaciones, pero el error de cors sigue apareciendo solo cuando subo videos, pero cuando subo imagenes lo hace con normalidad.  Es extraño porque es una sola ruta y un controller donde se sube imagenes o videos, pero por alguna razon el de videos trae problemas en la google run, en el back de mi local si funciona correctamente.